# SPICE how to assign a variable voltage generator for receiving antenna

Tags: voltage, antenna, spice, s-parameters, antenna-loop

I would like to do an AC analysis, noise analysis and signal to noise simulations using TINA TI - LT spice is OK

How do I assign a variable voltage with parameters to an AC voltage source in SPICE? If the voltage output of an receiving antenna increases with frequency that is

~ V = 2*pi*N*A*f. Parameters are:

N - number of turns

A - area of the loop

f - frequency

Thanks.

Comment: Is it for some form of RFID power transfer application. If so, shouldn't the model include a tuning capacitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to model the voltage response you want with a separate bit of circuitry and then buffer that voltage with an arbitrary voltage source.

[image]

This has the voltage response that you were looking for.

There could be a more elegant way to do it, but this should get you going.